# Angular upgrade 11 to 13 RXJS dependency

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular13

We recently migrated from Angular 11 to Angular 13, however I see the rxjs version is still 6.5.5. Is it required to upgrade RXJS to 7.4 or we can work with 6.5.5?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend reading up on Angular's official blog posts to find answers for common questions about core updates.

> First up, RxJS 7.4 is now the default for apps created with ng new. Existing apps using RxJS v6.x will have to manually update using the npm install rxjs@7.4 command.

https://blog.angular.io/angular-v13-is-now-available-cce66f7bc296

Comment: But why didn't angular updated their package.json to reflect that?

Comment: @GarfieldKlon I had the same question. I migrated from angular 11 to 13. And it did not upgrade the rxjs version. Very strange..

Comment: RxJS introduced some breaking changes between version 6 and 7. So, my assumption is that the Angular team didn't want to force those breaking changes on everyone when they update their existing Angular project. I also assume this is a grace period, and future versions of Angular will make RxJS v7 a hard requirement when updating.